# How to display author meta and count numbers for each user in comment.php?

Tags: wp-query, theme-development

All users are registered to comment on the site, so what I want to achieve is, to display user details like the *meta info*, *description*, *url*, etc... So, if possible also the number of posts and comments published in the `comment.php` template.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting user's metas values :

```
$user_meta = get_user_meta($user_id, 'YOUR_META_KEY', TRUE); //You have to set the $user_id / And the "YOUR_META_KEY" can be description, name, custom meta...
```

To get user's comments count

```
function commentCount($userId = null) {
    global $wpdb;

    if($userId == null) return 0;

    $count = $wpdb->get_var('
             SELECT COUNT(comment_ID) 
             FROM ' . $wpdb->comments. ' 
             WHERE user_id = "' . $userId . '"');
    return (int)$count;
}
```

Finally, to get user's posts count

```
$user_post_count = count_user_posts( $userId , 'post' );
```

Comment: First of all, thx for the answer.  Finally I found that the key most importantly to this question, is to *get author comment id by comment id*.  So I used this to get *author comment id*    `$comment_id = $commentID;  $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );  $comment_author_id = $comment -> user_id;`

Comment: With the *$comment_author_id*, getting user's meta values and posts count work well. However getting user's comments count just failed n don't know how. Forgive me if I did not get your really point since I'm a newbie.  I found it can work with `global $wpdb; 
    $where = 'WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id = ' . $comment_author_id ;
    $comment_count = $wpdb->get_var(
    "SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total
    FROM {$wpdb->comments}
    {$where}
    ");`

Comment: Sry for the bad formatting, so complicated for me.

Comment: @poneland As I mentioned above, the most important thing is to have and set the ID of the user, no matter how you do it to get that ID...